# Can't change UIButton appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I'm trying to change the appearance of all the UIButtons in my app. This is the code I'm using to do so and when it gets called, nothing happens at all. I know the method itself is getting called because the NSLog is printing out the filename string. So there must be something else I'm doing wrong.

```
NSString *filename = @"image.png";
NSLog(filename);

UIImage *customBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:filename] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:customBackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This should help
[[UIButton appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: your code is ok! try to find another problem or give more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change Button collor or image from full of View you can do with :-

```
 for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view;

              [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
```

**other is**

```
 [[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: But the requirement is to change the appearance of buttons through out the app not in one specific view. So the code has to be generic

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful

```
[btnClear setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: So this works if I do it for one specific button but is there a way to do it for all buttons at once?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code looks good to me, providing it can find the image file. You might want to check `customBackground` is not null.

I've successfully done this myself with code that's exactly the same as yours, and called from the app delegate in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I'd try putting your code in this method if that isn't where you do it already.  This will apply the custom background throughout your app.